# Can I say "contribute for someone"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Can I say "The organization contributes for children in developing countries"
Can the word contribute have someone as objective?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177054/contribute-for-or-contribute-to-or-contribute-on-or-contribute-in

Comment: It doesn't sound fluent to me.  You normally contribute **to** something, so saying "the organization contributes for..." sounds awkward.  If you mean that the organization makes contributions for a specific purpose, it would sound better to rephrase the sentence.

Comment: Thank you mstorkson and stangon for taking your time to answer my question! I really appriciate.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your meaning, probably not. The sentence you've provided is unclear.

If the organization is contributing money to children in developing countries, you would use *to*.

> The organization contributes to children in developing countries.

The use of *for* is ambiguous, because it can mean one of two things:

> The organization contributes for children

In this case it can mean the same as the above *to* sentence, or it can also mean *on behalf* of the children. So perhaps the children gave the money to the organization and asked the organization to give the money to someone.

> I was unwell, so my brother posted the letter for me.

In this case it means he posted the letter (on my behalf).

> There was a cake addressed to her, and a cake addressed to me. First, she opened the cake for me. Then she opened her own cake.

In this case, she opened the cake that was intended to be given to me. She didn't open it on my behalf (for example, because I was not strong enough to open it).

Because of the ambiguity it doesn't sound very natural to a native speaker to use *for* in this case, and you should use *to*.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question. It was easy to understand!